# Have notification when you have junk mail in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Can you put it so you get notifications when you have mail in your junkmailfolder in Outlook 2010?

Comment: Yes just create a rule that displays a notification on that folder.

Comment: @Ramhound is correct, not to mention that the junk mail folder will show a green (#) next to it with unread items.

Comment: Doesnt seem like I can set rule on that folder.

Answer (score 0):

From [Here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-outlook/re-enable-the-junk-mail-notification/7565ce4e-4533-43c0-a3ac-747173e6e8d7)

You need to edit the registry.
Browse to this registry key - replacing the xx with your version number:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Outlook\Options\General`
delete 37 from the values.

Comment: 37 wasnt there just 35 and comma. Deleted that. But did not work

Comment: You will want to create a rule then as the above mentioned.